# How to top window in WIN8/WIN10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I try use SetWindowPos,But someone told me it was wrong to do that.

WIN32 program , How to top window in WIN8/WIN10 ? 
like the Task Manager。

Comment: Your sentences are incomprehensible

Comment: Strongly related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246590/is-task-manager-a-special-kind-of-always-on-top-window-for-windows-10

Comment: You can't make a window like task manager. Only the OS can do that.

Comment: Nothing that much wrong with SetWindowPos.  Any kind of "my window is more important than any other" attitude, that's 97.2% of the time wrong.  99.9% when asked at SO.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to make a window "top most".

When you create the window with [CreateWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx), specify `WS_EX_TOPMOST` as an extended style.

```
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, ...);
```

For an existing window, use SetWindowPos:

```
DWORD flags = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, flags);
```

Either way is fine.

Comment: @selble  DWORD dwType = GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
   dwType |= WS_EX_TOPMOST;
   SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, dwType);
   SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);

Comment: @daijiepei - yep.